# Which is the best AES mode of operation?

Tags: encryption, aes, modes-of-operation

Is there any reason to choose, say ECB over CBC? Or GCM over AEX? Or CTR over CFB? Is there a best AES mode of operation? And, when required, which is the best padding to use?

Comment: What do you want to encrypt? Data stream, disk or what? PS: You shouldn't never use ECB.

Comment: It really depends on your scenario and if you have separate authentication (and the order of Encrypt and MAC).

Comment: Data, @ventaquil. A python bytes like object to be specific.

Comment: I generally use CTR then a HMAC, because CTR is malleable.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 major types of mode of operation:

1. The mode requires an initialization vector, which is subdivided into

1.1. a random IV. AES-CBC falls under this category, and

1.2. a unique nonce. AES-GCM and AES-CCM falls under this category.

For either of these subcategory, you should use a mode that provides authenticity guarantee (ideally choose an AEAD mode), so you should go with AES-GCM, or less preferably AES-CCM.

2. The mode is a DAE (deterministic authenticated encryption), which many may not had encountered.

The AES-KW specified in NIST-SP-800-38-F is one such example, but it sometimes expands the ciphertext. I would recommend you look at AES-SIV in [RFC5297](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297).

For the other modes I've not mentioned, ECB simply eats your privacy for breakfast and you won't be able to implement XTS mode that interoperates with other mainstream systems.